# Trouble with installing openstack through devstack script

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon

[image: error message]

I am facing a problem while installing openstack through devstack script on my Ubuntu 15 lts.

It says:

> sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups"     AssertionError: sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups          ----------------------------------------   Rolling back uninstall of cryptography

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cryptography AssertionError: sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39829473/cryptography-assertionerror-sorry-but-this-version-only-supports-100-named-gro)

Answer (score 7):

Hi this is due to a pycparser 2.14 package update on pypi today. More details can be found in [1] and [2].

[1] http://lists.openstack.org/pipermail/openstack-dev/2016-October/104909.html
[2] https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/issues/147

Workaround to fix it is to change "pycparser===2.14"in /opt/stack/requirements/upper-constraints.txt to "pycparser===2.13"

Using pip to change the version will not work, because DevStack will uninstall 2.13 version and update it to 2.14, as required in the above file.

========================================================================
Update on 10/4(JST):
according to the update in [2], this bug has been resolved. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's an issue with pythons pycparser lib, install the previous version by setting pycparser==2.13 in your requirements.txt file or via pip.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and I resolve this issue after removing 'pycparser' package, using below command:

```
pip uninstall pycparser
```

Comment: this worked for me when installing [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) on Debian 8

Answer (score 0):

The source package of `pycparser` doesn't have this problem, only the wheel seems to fail. 
Using the `--no-binary` in your installation command or requirements file should make it work too.

I added `--no-binary pycparser` in the end of my requirements file and it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this so that it may help someone...

Our Devstack also failed because of this pycparser bug. We have just downgraded pycparser to 2.13 in requirement.txt/upper_requirement.txt and disabled 'tempest' service(This service will install cryptography and pycparser) in local.conf. After this, our Devstack installation was successful.

NOTE: comment the line 'RECLONE=yes' in local.conf file.

Thanks